# Number of items always the same when using Folder.Items.Count

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I do not undersand but it seems that the number of mails retrieved is constant at 254. Folder.Items.Count always return 254. When I run it every day. But I have more than 600 mails in the folder. 254 seems to be 1 year of mails. Are you aware of such limit ? Is there a way to get all the message in that folder ? Maybe by ajusting some parameters of the folder ?

````
Sub GetFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder

    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = Sheets("mails")
    sh.Activate
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' récupère le dossier Ratios
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Ratios")
    
    i = 2
    MsgBox Folder.Items.Count
    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.SenderName = "noreply.olisnet@caceis.com" And (Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 6) = "Alerte" Or Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 13) = "Récapitulatif") Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
            Cells(i, 2).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Cells(i, 3).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            i = i + 1
        Else
            MsgBox OutlookMail.Subject
        End If
    Next OutlookMail
    ```
    
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Sheets("Param").Activate

End Sub
````

Comment: Are there mails **only from** "noreply.olisnet@caceis.com", **all of them have a subject starting with "Alerte" or "Récapitulatif"**?

Comment: Is that a cached or an online profile? In the former case, do you sync all or only the latest emails? Can you actually see all 600 emails in Outlook?

Comment: yes I can see them.

Answer (score 2):

> 254 seems to be 1 year of mails. Are you aware of such limit ? Is there a way to get all the message in that folder ? Maybe by adjusting some parameters of the folder ?

In your mail profile you need to change caching settings. It seems you have set the caching age to only one year. That's why you see only 254 items in the Outlook folder. Other items are kept on the server.

In Outlook Account settings you may find the following:

[image: outlook account caching settings]

---

Another possible weak place is the `For Each` loop where you iterate over all items in the folder:

```
    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.SenderName = "noreply.olisnet@caceis.com" And (Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 6) = "Alerte" Or Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 13) = "Récapitulatif") Then
```

That is not really a good idea! The folder may contain many items and the loop can take much longer time to complete while the Outlook UI will be frozen. For that reason you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Great! It makes sense to mark the answer then.